# If I say "the men and women (without "the") are teachers", does "women" still refer to specific persons?

Tags: determiners

There are female teachers Mindy and Cindy and male teachers Michael and Nick.

The men (Michael and Nick) and the women (Mindy and Cindy) are teachers.

If I say "the men and women (without "the") are teachers", does "women" still specifically refer to Mindy and Cindy?

Comment: I think this question needs some additional detail - what is the context? And if you could explain further why you are unsure that will help focus the answer. Otherwise we're just proofreading and I can think of contexts where you might need one or the other, so neither is wrong unless you supply context.

Comment: @Astralbee I mean, is "the (x and y)" possible instead "the (x) and the (y)" like "both x and y"? It doesn't need specific contexts. Just generalization is all I want.

Comment: As I've just explained, a generalisation isn't possible because what might be correct in one context is not in another.

Comment: "The men and the women are teachers but the non-binary people are just there to observe." Or "The men and the women are teachers but the gorillas are classroom assistants." Unlikely but who knows?

Comment: @StuartF I revised it.

Comment: The revision makes more sense. I'd already written an answer tackling different possible contexts. Hopefully you can figure out which applies to your revision

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, the definite article "*the*" is used to refer to something *specific*. There are some occasions where we can use it to refer to something generic.

"*The men*" could be either of these, depending on the context. For example, "*the men in my office all have beards*" clearly refers to a specific, limited group of men at the present time, whereas in a statement like "*in Islam, the men have the responsibility to provide for their family*", 'the men' means all men from the past, present and future that subscribe to this belief.

The context you have supplied refers to a limited set of *specific* men and women. In this case it would not really matter whether you said "*the men and women*" or simply "*the men and the women*", but using the definite article twice would certainly emphasise the inclusion of both genders, if that is your point. In answer to your question, yes, you could use a predeterminer and say "*both the men and the women*" to emphasise that further.

In other contexts where you might want to make a more general statement about men and women in a particular arrangement that will apply more broadly to people from the past or the future and not just a specific set previously mentioned then you could drop the articles and simply say "*both men and women*".

Answer (score 0):

> There are female teachers, Mindy and Cindy, and male teachers, Michael
> and Nick. The men and women
> are teachers.

As two sentences together, you needn't repeat the determiner the. But you can if you want to. It's your choice.However, it is a good idea to set off the teachers' names with commas to signal they are appositives.